# how to turn an observable object into an observable array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this observable object in my angular project that has this type:

```
  export interface FavoritesResponse {
    wallet: boolean;
    deposit: boolean;
    withdraw: boolean;
    transfer: boolean;
    exchange: boolean;
    ticket: boolean;
    account: boolean;
  }
```

I want to extract an `array` from this object with only the properties that have the value `true`.

So for example if my favorites object looks like this:

```
  favorites$ = {
    wallet: true;
    deposit: true;
    withdraw: false;
    transfer: false;
    exchange: false;
    ticket: true;
    account: true;
  }
```

I want to have my enabledFavorites$ look like this:

```
  enabledFavorites$ = [
    wallet,
    deposit,
    ticket,
    account
  ]
```

as in, turn it into an array and only have the keys that had the value of true. How can I do this? I know the solution probably contains an rxjs pipe, map but I don't know what I should be doing exactly.

Comment: Your question doesn't include any observables? Unclear what you're asking for. enabledFavorites$ makes no sense as posted...what is 'wallet', 'deposit' etc. within this array

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to say the observable emits an object of type `FavoritesResponse` and you wish to transform the emission to an array of it's keys only with value `true`, you could use

1. RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator to transform the incoming object
2. Native JS methods [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to perform the actual transformation

```js
enabledFavorites$: Observable<string[]> = favorites$.pipe(
  map((favs: FavoritesResponse) => 
    Object.keys(favs).filter((key: string) => !!favs[key])
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get favoritesArray$(): Observable<string[]> {
return this.favoritesSettings$.pipe(
  map((favorites) => {
    const _items = Object.keys(favorites);
    const _result: string[] = [];

    _items.forEach((item) => {
      if (!!(favorites as any)[item]) {
        _result.push(item);
      }
    });

    return _result;
  })
);
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So I guess that you want is convert from `Observable<FavoritesResponse>` to `Observable<string[]>` with the `string[]` containing the keys checked.

One way could be:

```
  const enabledFav$ = favOptions$.pipe(
    map(resp => {
      let result = [];
      Object.keys(resp).forEach(key => {
        if (resp.key) {
          result.push(key);
        }
      });
      return result;
    })
  );
```

I dont know the scenario but this is basically the code.

Here `enabledFav$`is `Observable<string[]>` and favOptions$ is `Observable<FavoritesResponse>`